# Find min and max of pandas indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, max, min

I have a dataframe called df_paths. And in this dataframe I have user and trial. And for each time I have a value of v and u. I want to calculate the max value of v for each trial of each user and add that to a column. How would I go about this?

See image for a snapshot of the dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If need aggregate values use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['user','trial']).agg(max_u = ('u','max'),
                                      min_u = ('u','min'),
                                      max_v = ('v','max'),
                                      min_v = ('v','min'))
```

If need new columns use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['user','trial'])
df[['max_u','max_v']] = g[['u','v']].transform('max')
df[['min_u','min_v']] = g[['u','v']].transform('min')
```